# Apache coyote vulnerability fixes are causing wrong port usage

Tags: java, security, tomcat, coyote

I'm using an embedded tomcat server in one of my java project. the creation of server looks like

```
Tomcat _tomcat = new Tomcat();
```

i have configured the Tomcat server to use port numbers from 9001
everything was working fine.

**Problem statement**

To address the Apache coyote vulnerability which was addressed in a nessus scan i have modified the tomcat server creation to

```
Tomcat _tomcat = new Tomcat();
_tomcat.getConnector().setXpoweredBy(false);
_tomcat.getConnector().setProperty("server", "");
```

after doing this change tomcat server is binding to port number 8080, which i have not configured anywhere, this is causing issue when i try to run two instances at once. gives the below error. [Tomcat server unable to bind error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft5gz.png)

**Question**

How to avoid tomcat server from using port 8080 with apache coyote vulnerability fixes?

Comment: What talking about a vulnerability you should always name it (e.g. by CVE number). It would also be helpful if you could include the version of tomcat you were using before updating (because of the vulnerability) and now after.

Comment: I don't have a CVE number, this vulnerability was reported as part of Nessus scan. I'm using Tomcat 9.0.65 but upgrading the version will not solve this issue, we have to hide the server details to address the issue, which is what i'm doing in the second code snippet i shared, and that's causing the issue.

Comment: If the vulnerability was reported by nessus why don't you include that in your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here when you do `_tomcat.getConnector()` a connector instance is called which is not yet initialized, and it uses default values and listens at port 8080 which is default port for a tomcat Connector instance.

instead of performing `setXpoweredBy(false)` and `setProperty("server", "")` on defualt instance of connector, move this part to where you are creating tomcat Connector instance. something like

```
Connector connector = new Connector();
connector.setPort(port); 
connector.setXpoweredBy(false);
connector.setProperty("server", "");
```

and then set this connector to tomcat server

```
_tomcat.setConnector(connector);
```